# HTML input does not get Highlighted/Selected

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, c#-4.0

We are developing ASP.Net application.
We have used HTML Input control .
But we are facing problem to select/highlight the value in control.

On some pages My Html Input control on Div, User Control.
May this be the reason?

[image]

Comment: Did the answers help you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

In javascript you can use `.focus()` this to manually focus the textbox

```
document.getElementById('txtMemo').focus();
```

With plain markup you could use `autofocus` attribute.

```
<input type="text" id="txtMemo" autofocus />
```

[autofocus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Forms_in_HTML#The_autofocus_attribute) is introduced in HTML5, so older browsers won't have support for it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the focus function on doc ready to select the particular field you want to select first. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#txtMemo').focus;
});
```

Of course this is also assuming you are using jQuery.